# How to keep a moving div inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game where a mouse has to navigate a maze to find the block of cheese. But I can't seem to figure out how to keep the mouse within the game area, if anyone could guide me along the way it would be appreciated!

```
let mazeBG = document.getElementById("gamearea");
let mouse = document.getElementById("snake");
let cheese = document.getElementById("food");
let game  = 1;
let posY = 0;
let posX = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(key){
    if (key.keyCode == 38){
        posY -= 5;
        mouse.style.top = posY + "px";
    } else if (key.keyCode == 39){
        posX += 5;
        mouse.style.left = posX + "px";
    } else if (key.keyCode == 37){
        posX -= 5;
        mouse.style.left = posX + "px";
    } else if (key.keyCode == 40){
        posY += 5;
        mouse.style.top = posY + "px";
    };
};
```

Comment: Please, provide more complete code snippet including HTML and that part of JS code where you create `gamearea`, `snake`, and `food`.

Comment: Gamearea, snake, and food are just divs in html with css styles (theyre named like that because it was originally going to be snake game but I wanted to do something more original) @Arfeo

Comment: Do you need to know the size of the mouse and the gamearea? @Arfeo

Comment: Nope, I can calculate them. =) So, if I understood correctly, all three divs are separate ones and are not parents or children of each other?

Comment: Every div the game is a child of the gamearea. And the mouse has a position relative if that will do anything. @Arfeo

Comment: Than just get the size of the gamearea div and check if posX / posY reached, ie. mazeBG.height(); and mazeBG.width();

Comment: Can you write out how that might look? @Milan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
let mazeBG = document.getElementById("gamearea");
let mouse = document.getElementById("snake");
let cheese = document.getElementById("food");
let game  = 1;
let posY = 0;
let posX = 0;
const step = 5;

document.onkeydown = (key) => {
    if (key.keyCode == 38){
        if (posY >= step) {
          posY -= step;
          mouse.style.top = posY + "px";
        }
    } else if (key.keyCode == 39){
            if (posX <= (600 - step - 20)) { // Width of gamearea - step - width of the avatar
          posX += step;
          mouse.style.left = posX + "px";
        }
    } else if (key.keyCode == 37){
          if (posX >= step) {
          posX -= step;
          mouse.style.left = posX + "px";
        }
    } else if (key.keyCode == 40){
        if (posY <= (400 - step - 20)) { // Height of gamearea - step - height of the avatar
          posY += step;
          mouse.style.top = posY + "px";
        }
    };
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tcbnka1m/

Although, I strongly recommend using canvas animation if you are making a game.

Comment: This is a correct answer, I'd use .width() and .height() on mazeBG and mouse for completeness

Comment: I would use canvas animation, but I make games to learn javascript in a more fun way and I want to eliminate the amount of css animations im using for now.